# Different scroll speed with overflow:scroll

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, mousewheel

I divided page into nonscrollable header and scrollable content. Both are placed as "position:fixed" and content uses "overflow:scroll". This works great, but I noticed that scroll speed changed in Firefox, now mouse wheel scrolls much slower. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll speed is determined by the browser. CSS and Javascript don't have any way to affect system settings.

Comment: "overflow:scroll" at times be 5 or 10 times slower than the browsers built-in non-styled scroll bars.

Answer (score 0):

Iam assuming that you are concerned about scrolling being not as smooth as you want it to be. There is not much you can do here. The "overflow:scroll" performance will vary across browsers and Iam pretty sure if you check your app in a mobile browser you will find a lot of variation in scrolling speed and smoothness.

The best hack you can do is enable hardware acceleration for browsers where you can encounter this issue with the following css.

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```

You should put this property on element which overflow:scroll set.
But this property has its side-effects. It tends to use more memory and may result in crashes.